# How to debug TypeScript with breakpoint in Jetbrain IDE?

Tags: typescript, debugging

I have an Angular frontend and express with Typescript backend. I want to debug both side. I could not find a clear step by step tutorial/video on **how to debug TypeScript with breakpoint in Jetbrain IDE  (Webstrom, PhpStorm,...)?** When I google, I find tutorials for Vscode. 
I know the first step is to generate source map by setting `"sourceMap": true,` in tsconfig.json but then what next?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-by-step instruction from setting up a brand new TypeScript project to debugging it in WebStorm:

1. Create a tiny project

   ```
   mkdir ts
   cd ts 
   npm install --save typescript source-map-support
   ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --init`
   ```
2. Make sure you have `sourceMap` set to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`.
3. Create a simple **index.ts**:

   ```
   let i = 1;
   let j = 2;
   let k = i + j;
   console.log(k);
   ```
4. Open the project in WebStorm. Open `index.ts`. Wait that WebStorm has finished indexing the project:

[image: WebStorm indexing running]

4. Open the WebStorm preferences. Find the "TypeScript" section on the left. Make sure the "Node interpreter" and "TypeScript" fields are properly filled. Enable the "TypeScript Language Service" checkbox and let WebStorm "Recompile on changes". Click "OK".

[image: Setting up TypeScript support]

5. In the Run toolbar, click "Add Configuration":

[image: Add Run configuration]

6. Create a new "Node.js" configuration:

   [image: Create a new NodeJS configuration]

   - Use "index.js" as your "JavaScript file". This should be the compiled file that you wish to execute.
   - As "Node parameters", use `--require source-map-support/register`. This enables you to get the correct lines while debugging in WebStorm.

[image: Create actual run config]

7. Click "OK".
8. Create a new breakpoint in your `index.ts` by clicking on the side-panel on the left of the given line:

[image: Create break point]

9. In the Run toolbar, now click the debug button. Make sure that your run configuration is selected in the drop-down left of it:

[image: Debug]

10. The Debug tool window will open, stopping at the breakpoint:
    [image: Debug view]